# Use a custom field type in Matrix Blocks - Craft 3

Tags: matrix, craft3, custom-fieldtype

I'd like to create a field of type Dropdown/Table (or even use a field from a plugin like color-swatches) and have it available when selecting a matrix block element field type:

[image]

In this case, it's for creating a field containing a set of color values, a palette.

I'd like to know whether or not this is a common approach and what solutions do you usually give to this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what it has to do with a matrix - you can use every field normally and inside a matrix, there is no restriction - but I usually create a custom field type.

You can see how to create Plugins in the [documentation](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/plugin-intro.md) all available fields in Craft extends the base [Field](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/base/Field.php) class

There are function like [getInputHtml](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/base/Field.php#L279) where you define the html that should be displayed while you create your entry/category and the function [serializeValue](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/base/Field.php#L345) that defines which value should be saved into the db.

You should take a look at the default Craft [fields](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/develop/src/fields) to get used to it. Change the values you need and create your own field.

However: I think the most common approach is to look what Pixel and Tonic does and understand how it works. Then you can create custom fields via Plugin or Module

**Edit**
You can see how to register custom fields [here](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/field-types.md). As you can see they say the same

> You can refer to Craft’s own field classes for examples